# using int (32-bit) vs cast to ushort

Tags: c#, casting

I have an array of bytes and a struct. I want to set some of struct members to some of array members this way:

```cs
mystruct.m1 = (myarr[0] << 8) | myarr[1];    //join bytes
```

So `mystruct.m1` is going to be a 16-bit integer (ushort). However, if I define `mystruct.m1` as ushort, I should cast `(myarr[0] << 8) | myarr[1]` to ushort or Visual Studio says `cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'ushort'`. But if I use normal int, no cast is needed.

Which one is better and more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A byte in C# is unsigned (values 0 to 255). Therefore I would go with `ushort` as well.

> Which one is better?

The one that provides better semantics to future readers. With an `ushort`, it's immediately clear that only 2 bytes will fit in. If you use an `int` instead, one might wonder what the other 16 bits are good for.

Also, with `int`, bit-shift operations may work differently in case the value is negative for whatever reason.

> Which one is more efficient?

Why care about efficiency if you have no performance problem?